# How to use dateCreated and lastUpdated in Hibernate without using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate

In earlier projects I have used `grails` framework where I have used Date `lastUpdated` and Date `dateCreated`. It worked in `grails`. Do we have such things in `Hibernate` only so that I can use it for `lastUpdated` or `dateCreated`?

Actually I could not find good example in `.NET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version, please check the syntax for hbm files.
Though we prefer updating the date/time using API before saving the object.

Comment: thanx ...but gan u provide me any link for references ?
I got stuck into it .. THough itz my fist day of using Hibernate... wondering what to do  :p  :(

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version but it won't do what you want, you will have to do it manually